# Wordpress open_basedir error on /dev/urandom

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress show the following error message:

`Error message: 2 - is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/dev/urandom) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/website.nl/:/tmp/)<br /> on line68 in file /var/www/vhosts/website.nl/httpdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/class-phpass.php`

I could add `/dev/urandom` to the open `base_dir` but is it safe? If not, how would I bypass this error?

This is the code around line 68:

```
function get_random_bytes($count)
{
    $output = '';
    if ( @is_readable('/dev/urandom') && // <-- line 68
        ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))) {
        $output = fread($fh, $count);
        fclose($fh);
    }
```

It was to be expected that a file named "php ass" will render an error, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I never had that error before and didn't even know the existence of those lines of code from get_random_bytes, if you ask me and you are concerned about opening base dir to that path aswell, then just use another function from native PHP (if you have the ability to edit the part of code which is calling that get_random_bytes).

p.s.= that last row literally killed me, made my day!